# How can I repair screw holes in a PVC door?

Tags: doors

We removed a doorbell from a UPVC door. There are two small screw holes left,  but they're not smooth. What filler is best and how can I make them smooth?

Comment: A photo would be great. Solutions depend on location, etc. Frankly, I'd just reinstall appropriate screws to minimize the appearance. Filling holes in plastic doesn't usually conceal them. Welcome, and please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Screws in uPVC usually leave small raised areas when removed, so your task is two-fold.

First, you have to remove the raised area without further damaging the surrounding plastic. You can't sand it, you will need a modelling knife held at an angle to make a very slight chamfer/countersink round the existing holes.

Then you need to fill.
Silicone will be too shiny, though long-lasting.
Decorators caulk will initially be a good visual match, but will yellow with age, and also if it is repeatedly wetted, will start to fail.
No 'cement-based' household filler will look right.

That leaves you with a specialist *exterior* caulk - you can get these specifically to fit & fill uPVC. It's not as shiny as silicone, & is completely weatherproof.

A UK example - https://www.unibond.co.uk/en/products/sealants/outdoor-sealants.html

It's not cheap, especially as you'll be using two tiny dots of it & the rest will likely set in the tube before you get around to needing it, but it should match & it should last a lifetime.